# Regex positive lookbehind woes

Tags: java, regex

My goal is to match the first 0 and everything after that zero in a decimal value.  If the first decimal place is a zero then I want to match the decimal too.  If there is no decimal then capture nothing.

Here are some examples of what I want:

```
180.570123 // should capture the "0123" on the end
180.570    // should capture the "0" on the end
180.0123   // should capture the ".0123" on the end
180.0      // should capture the ".0" on the end
180123     // should capture nothing
180        // should capture nothing
```

If the first decimal place is a 0 then making the match is easy:

```
(\.0.*)
```

My problem is matching when the first decimal place is not a 0.  I believe positive lookbehind will fix this issue, but I am not able to get it to work correctly.  Here is one regex I have tried:

```
(?<=^.*\..*)0.*
```

This regex will eventually be used in Java.

**UPDATE:**

I am going to use this regex to get rid of numbers and possibly a decimal point on the end of a string using Java's `replaceAll` method.  I will do this by replacing the capture group with an empty string.  Here is a better example of what I want.

```
String case1 = "180.570123";
String case2 = "180.570";
String case3 = "180.0123";
String case4 = "180.0";
String case5 = "180123";
String case6 = "180";

String result = null;

result = case1.replaceAll( "THE REGEX I NEED", "" );
System.out.println( result ); // should print 180.57

result = case2.replaceAll( "THE REGEX I NEED", "" );
System.out.println( result ); // should print 180.57

result = case3.replaceAll( "THE REGEX I NEED", "" );
System.out.println( result ); // should print 180

result = case4.replaceAll( "THE REGEX I NEED", "" );
System.out.println( result ); // should print 180

result = case5.replaceAll( "THE REGEX I NEED", "" );
System.out.println( result ); // should print 180123

result = case6.replaceAll( "THE REGEX I NEED", "" );
System.out.println( result ); // should print 180
```

Also, I am testing these regexs at http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this expression:

```
\.[1-9]*(0\d*)
```

And what you want will be in the first capturing group. (Except the decimal point.)

If you want to capture the decimal point too, you can use:

```
(?:\.[1-9]+|(?=\.))(\.?0\d*)
```

Example ([online](http://ideone.com/jWGxI)):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:\\.[1-9]+|(?=\\.))(\\.?0\\d*)");

String[] strs = {"180.570123", "180.570", "180.0123", "180.0", "180123", "180", "180.2030405"};

for (String s : strs) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    System.out.printf("%-12s: Match: %s%n", s,
        m.find() ? m.group(1) : "n/a");
}
```

Output:

```
180.570123  : Match: 0123
180.570     : Match: 0
180.0123    : Match: .0123
180.0       : Match: .0
180123      : Match: n/a
180         : Match: n/a
180.2030405 : Match: 030405
```

Comment: That captures case 1 incorrectly and does not capture case 2 or 4 at all.

Comment: @typoknig, updated. And case 1 was always matched correctly. *Use the content of the first capturing group, not the whole match.*

Comment: Ah, I see.  It does seem to be working when use the content of the first capture group as you said.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I would write a small function to do the extracting instead of regex.

```
private String getZeroPart(final String s) {
        final String[] strs = s.split("\\.");
        if (strs.length != 2 || strs[1].indexOf("0") < 0) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return strs[1].startsWith("0") ? "." + strs[1] : strs[1].substring(strs[1].indexOf("0"));
        }
    }
```

to test it:

```
final String[] ss = { "180.570123", "180.570", "180.0123", 
"180.0", "180123", "180", "180.2030405","180.5555" };

        for (final String s : ss) {
            System.out.println(getZeroPart(s));
        }
```

output:

```
0123
0
.0123
.0
null
null
030405
null
```

**update**

based on the EDIT of the question. do some changes on the method to get the right number:

```
private String cutZeroPart(final String s) {
    final String[] strs = s.split("\\.");
    if (strs.length != 2 || strs[1].indexOf("0") < 0) {
        return s;
    } else {
        return strs[1].startsWith("0") ? strs[0] : s.substring(0, strs[0].length() + strs[1].indexOf("0") + 1);
    }
}
```

output:

```
180.570123 -> 180.57
180.570 -> 180.57
180.0123 -> 180
180.0 -> 180
180123 -> 180123
180 -> 180
180.2030405 -> 180.2
180.5555 -> 180.5555
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It is nice to have options, but I think the regex way is a bit cleaner :)

Answer (score 0):

Lookbehinds might be overkill.  This one worked well-->

`/\.\d*(0\d*)/`

Comment: That captures case 1 incorrectly and does not capture case 2, 3, or 4 at all.

Comment: But not that case to capture the decimal and the following 0.  What do you expect here: `180.0407`

Comment: The group captures what you want, except for the .0 case.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?<=(\\.))(\\d*?)(0.*)").matcher("180.2030405");
        String res="";
        if(m.find()){
            if(m.group(2).equals("")){
                res = "."+m.group(3);
            }
            else{
                res = m.group(3);
            }
        }
```